Statistical approach for analyzing volume-outcome relationship in PCI with varying complexity between hospital types
I am working on a study to assess the volume-outcome relationship in PCI (Percutaneous Coronary Intervention). I have a dataset that includes detailed information on:
Operator characteristics, including:
Lifetime PCI experience (total number of procedures performed by each operator).
Years since their first STEMI procedure.
Hospital type: whether each operator works in a university hospital or a non-university hospital.
Hospital PCI volume: overall PCI volume for each hospital.
From previous studies, I know that 30-day mortality is commonly used as the primary outcome for volume-outcome analyses, but I also have data on other patient outcomes like bleeding complications and more.
The problem Is that University hospitals tend to handle more complex cases, which may result in lower PCI volume per operator compared to non-university hospitals.
Non-university hospitals, on the other hand, generally handle higher volumes of PCI procedures but typically deal with less complex cases.
What would be the best statistical model to assess this volume-outcome relationship? Specifically:
How can I account for the fact that operators in university hospitals may have lower PCI volume due to higher case complexity, whereas non-university hospitals may have higher PCI volume but less complex cases?
Should I use a multivariable mixed effects logistic regression model with random effects for hospitals and operators to account for this clustering, or is there another method that might be more appropriate for these data?
Any advice on how to model this, or examples of similar analyses, would be greatly appreciated.

Welcome to Cross Validated :)

How can I account for the fact that operators in university hospitals may have lower PCI volume due to higher case complexity, whereas non-university hospitals may have higher PCI volume but less complex cases?

I would suggest that you include an indicator variable for hospital type (university hospital or not) and then interact that variable with Operator PCI volume and also Hospital PCI volume. The former will test whether the relationship between operator PCI volume and mortality differs between university and non-university hospitals, and the latter will test whether hospital PCI volume affects outcomes differently between university and non-university hospitals, potentially capturing how higher volume interacts with the complexity of cases handled.

Should I use a multivariable mixed effects logistic regression model with random effects for hospitals and operators to account for this clustering, or is there another method that might be more appropriate for these data?

I would suggest the mixed model approach, although you might consider generalised estimating equations too.

Any advice on how to model this, or examples of similar analyses, would be greatly appreciated.

There are a few things to consider:
Nested or Crossed Random Effects ?
If operators only work at one hospital, variability due to operators is dependent on their hospital and the random effects structure would be nested
If operators work at multiple hospitals, the random effects for hospitals and operators should be crossed.
To read more about crossed vs nested random effects, please refer to this thread:
Crossed vs nested random effects: how do they differ and how are they specified correctly in lme4?
Operator Coding
The operator coding should reflect whether operators work at multiple hospitals. If an operator works exclusively at one hospital, you would assign them a unique ID per hospital. If an operator works across multiple hospitals, ensure that the same operator ID appears across hospitals. For instance, if you have an operator named "Operator_A" who works in both Hospital 1 and Hospital 2, you should use the same operator ID to indicate that this operator contributes to outcomes in both hospitals. Please refer to the link I just gave above regarding coding of the two grouping variables
Residual Covariance Structure
Consider whether residual correlation is an issue, if there is repeated data collection over time for certain hospitals or operators. If so, you may need to specify a covariance structure (eg., AR(1), compound symmetry, unstructured etc.) to account for residual correlation within hospitals. However, if this is not applicable to your study design, the default assumption of independence between observations may suffice.  Please refer to the following thread for a discussion of different residual covariance structures.
Beyond AR(1) as a covariance structure for mixed models with repeated measures
Handling Case Complexity
Case complexity can be operationalised, for example using a standardised risk score like EuroSCORE or a composite of relevant patient variables (eg., age, comorbidities, percentage of STEMI cases). If case complexity is continuous, include it directly as a covariate. If categorised, include it as a categorical fixed effect. However, I would like to draw your attention to possible problems with composite variable bias. See some related work by former colleagues of mine: Tomova et al (2022a and 2022b) and Berrie et al (2024).
References
Berrie, L., Arnold, K. F., Tomova, G. D., Gilthorpe, M. S., & Tennant, P. W. (2024). Depicting deterministic variables within directed acyclic graphs (DAGs): An aid for identifying and interpreting causal effects involving derived variables and compositional data. American Journal of Epidemiology, kwae153.
Tomova, G. D., Arnold, K. F., Gilthorpe, M. S., & Tennant, P. W. (2022). Adjustment for energy intake in nutritional research: a causal inference perspective. The American journal of clinical nutrition, 115(1), 189-198.
Tomova, Georgia D., Mark S. Gilthorpe, and Peter WG Tennant. "Theory and performance of substitution models for estimating relative causal effects in nutritional epidemiology." The American Journal of Clinical Nutrition 116, no. 5 (2022): 1379-1388.
